# How to find indexOf in a String array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexof

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String output = "";
            char[] input = textArea.getText().toUpperCase().toCharArray();
            int index;

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                if(input[i] != ' ') {
                    index = Arrays.asList(russian).indexOf(input[i]);
                    output += codeMorse[index] + " ";
                }
            }

            textArea.setText(output);
            button.setText("Конвертировано!");
        }
    });
```

//arrays

```
    char[] russian = new char[]{'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З', 'И',
                            'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С',
                            'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ы', 'Ь',//41
                            'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                            '8', '9', '0' };

String[] codeMorse = new String[] { "*–", "–***", "*––", "––*",
                                    "–**", "*", "***–", "––**",
                                    "**", "*–––", "–*–", "*–**", //41
                                    "––", "–*", "–––", "*––*",
                                    "*–*", "***", "–", "**–",
                                    "**–*", "****", "–*–*",
                                    "–––*", "––––", "−−*−",
                                    "−*−−", "−**−", "**−**",
                                    "**−−", "*−*−", "*−−−−",
                                    "**−−−", "***−−", "****−",
                                    "*****", "−****", "−−***",
                                    "−−−**", "−−−−*", "−−−−−" };
```

//input value is "привет"

this code throws  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 exception. Both arrays in the same length. I think it throws due to indexOf, but I dont know how to change it.

Comment: This is saying that `input[i]` isn't in the `russian` array. You show the value of neither, so it's hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: but it is in..(

Comment: Either Java is being capricious and is lying to you; or it really isn't. Please show the definition of the `russian` array. My guess is that either `russian` is a `char[]` (in which case `Arrays.asList(russian)` is a `List<char[]>`, which never contains a `char`; or it's a `String[]`, in which case it doesn't contain a `char` either.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack logs?

Comment: russian is a char[]. but then how to change code that it works.....

Comment: stack logs dont fit in a comment

Comment: i know that, but i dont understand why

Comment: You should edit that `russian` array and the stack trace _into_ the question itself instead of putting them here in the comments.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: First, secure that code, [`List.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) can return -1, explaining your exception. Then, edit your code to show the array and the input value (remove those `edittext` to show us values) to be able to find why you are not able to find the value your are looking for.

Comment: now it's right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your characters may not be in your `russian` array.

You use `toUpperCase()`, which has not specified a `Locale`. Do specify a `Locale`, like `new Locale("ru")` to it, as it may convert your lower case letters incorrectly otherwise.

Also non alphanumerical characters should cause problems.

Try something like this:

```
private static final Locale RUSSIAN = new Locale("ru");

private static final String russian = "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЫЬ" + // 41
                                      "ЭЮЯ1234567890";

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String output = "";
            char[] input = textArea.getText().toUpperCase(RUSSIAN).toCharArray();
            int index;

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                index = russian.indexOf(input[i]);
                System.out.printf("char: %c, index: %d%n", input[i], index);
                if (index >= 0)
                    output += codeMorse[index] + " ";
            }

            textArea.setText(output);
            button.setText("Конвертировано!");
        }
    });
```

### Converted `char[]` to `String` to remove `Arrays.asList()`...

Comment: i try, and it doesnt throws exception but textArea is empty.

Comment: В(input[i]) -1(index)

Comment: В -1
В -1
О -1
Д -1
И -1
Т -1
Е -1
Т -1
Е -1
К -1
С -1
Т -1
. -1
. -1

Comment: whatever write, index equals -1

Comment: The cause might be, that `char[]` is an `Object`, and `asList()` treats it as a single `Object`, returns a `list` that consists of that single object...

Comment: thank you so much, that solve my problem!!! thank you aagain!! I understand that asList keep whole char[] as 1 value.

Answer (score -3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
                if(input[i] != ' ') {
                    index = Arrays.asList(russian).indexOf(input[i]);
                    output += codeMorse[index] + " ";
                }
            }
```

You just iterate till  `length-1`

Comment: the same situation